# How to substitute curly braces in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling embedding some code in ktools Photostore.
The only thing we try is to create a site including a wufoo form which results in an error.

User support responded to me:

> Content input in to the editor cannot use the characters { or }. These are reserved for the Smarty Template Engine.

So my questions is: how to parse this code to embed my form?

The Code:

```
var xyz;
(function (d, t) {
  var s = d.createElement(t),
    options = {
      'userName': 'abc',
      'formHash': 'xyz',
      'autoResize': true,
      'height': '400',
      'async': true,
      'host': 'wufoo.com',
      'header': 'show',
      'ssl': true
    };
  s.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.wufoo.com/scripts/embed/form.js';
  s.onload = s.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var rs = this.readyState;
    if (rs) if (rs != 'complete') if (rs != 'loaded') return;
    try {
      xyz = new WufooForm();
      zyx.initialize(options);
      xyz.display();
    } catch (e) {
    }
  };
  var scr = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],
    par = scr.parentNode;
  par.insertBefore(s, scr);
})(document, 'script');
```

Comment: To to format your code properly before you post it in a question please

Comment: I don't know if it would work but have you tried escaping the braces?

Comment: Where are you trying to put `"{"` or `"}"` in the form?

Comment: Sorry, not used to this editor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4501 did you check this?

Comment: Code is embedded via <script type="text/javascript">.

Comment: Did you read http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.escaping.tpl Tells you what to do.

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot: Yeah, that made the trick! Thank you very much, it works!

Comment: Ok, I will just add it as answer then. Glad to help.

Comment: Seems like someone already added the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is right in the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.escaping.tpl)

> In Smarty templates, the { and } braces will be ignored so long as they are surrounded by white space. This behavior can be disabled by setting the Smarty class variable $auto_literal to false.

or

> {literal}..{/literal} blocks are used for escaping blocks of template logic. You can also escape the braces individually with {ldelim},{rdelim} tags or {$smarty.ldelim},{$smarty.rdelim} variables.